Spring Boot 3.4.0 An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Unable to obtain X509Certificate from current request
I'm doing migration from Spring Boot 3.2.8 to 3.4.0 and Spring Cloud 2023.0.3 to 2024.0.0. My application uses OAuth2 with Spring Security in quite a normal way:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@EnableFeignClients
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(JwtDecoder decoder, HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(httpRequests -> httpRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .oauth2ResourceServer(jwtConf -> jwtConf.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.decoder(decoder)));
        return http.build();
    }
}

Here's my application.yml:
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jws-algorithms: ${JWS_ALGORITHMS}
          issuer-uri: ${ISSUER_URI}
          jwk-set-uri: ${JWK_SET_URI}

With Spring Boot 3.2.8 everything works fine, but after I switch the version to 3.4.0 incoming requests start failing with
org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.InvalidBearerTokenException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Unable to obtain X509Certificate from current request.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54) ~[spring-security-core-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.14.1.jar:1.14.1]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-6.4.1.jar:6.4.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.0.jar:6.2.0]

Here is how my jwks.json looks like:
 "keys" : [ {
    "kty" : "RSA",
    "use" : "sig",
    "alg" : "PS256",
    "kid" : "kid",
    "x5c" : [ "lost-of-chars==" ],
    "x5t#S256" : "lost-of-chars",
    "e" : "AQAB",
    "n" : "lost-of-chars"
  }

I've looked into migration guide but haven't found any clue. My question is how could I fix this.
P.S. The same happens with Spring Boot 3.3.0

Currently I work this around with this declaration
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoderByJwkKeySetUri(
        ObjectProvider<JwkSetUriJwtDecoderBuilderCustomizer> customizers,
        OAuth2ResourceServerProperties properties
) {
    var jwt = properties.getJwt();
    var builder = NimbusJwtDecoder
            .withJwkSetUri(jwt.getJwkSetUri())
            .jwsAlgorithms(signatureAlgorithms ->
                    jwt.getJwsAlgorithms().stream().map(SignatureAlgorithm::from).forEach(signatureAlgorithms::add)
            );
    customizers.orderedStream().forEach((customizer) -> customizer.customize(builder));

    var issuerUri = jwt.getIssuerUri();
    var validators = List.of(new JwtIssuerValidator(issuerUri), new JwtTimestampValidator());
    var defaultValidator = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(validators);

    var nimbusJwtDecoder = builder.build();
    nimbusJwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(defaultValidator);
    return nimbusJwtDecoder;
}

However, I suspect to do migration in a proper way I need to supply certificate somehow.

That is related to Support Certificate-Bound (POP) JWT Access Token Validation, which added X509CertificateThumbprintValidator by default in Spring Security 6.3.0(correspond to Spring Boot 3.3.0).

An OAuth2TokenValidator responsible for validating the x5t#S256 claim (if available) in the Jwt against the SHA-256 Thumbprint of the supplied X509Certificate.

Since x5t#S256 exist in your jwks.json, such validation will be triggered.
However, the client certificate is not present in the request. Likely mutual TLS has to be enabled.
Reference:

Mutual-TLS Client Certificate-Bound Access Tokens
Implementing 2 way SSL using Spring Boot

